# add_action without a do_action?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have found `add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed'` all over the woocommerce files but I can not find the matching `do_action` anywhere. I even ran a grep search for it and it doesn't seem to exist! Yet the hooks are being called so I know they must exist somewhere right? I need to find this `do_action` so that I can see what parameters it passes. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I believe you are looking for https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/includes/class-wc-order.php#L363